# Fast and Responsive GridView for data acquisition?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, grid, telerik

My use case is to log millions of messages into a customizable grid GUI (e.g. similar features of DevExpress and Telerik's Win Form Datagrids). Since this should be used for logs from specific hardware I'm forced to use as a storage a file or a flat database (excluded SQL&Co)

The gridview shall be customizable and fast on inserting new rows and when grouping/filtering/formatting. All these operations need to be done while the grid collects data on a pace of ~1000 events/second.

Does somebody used one of these grids for this specific purpose?
What you would recommend?

Thanks

PS: After a rough test, Telerik's Grid looks to have better performance.

Comment: How many items are you planning on showing per page?

Comment: Actually all events need to be visible. No paging.

Comment: What kind of super-human users are going to be able to assimilate millions of messages on a 1024x768 display?

Comment: They will start with millions and then filter out the irrelevant information until they get to an amount of information that they could handle. The problem is, they don't know what's irelevant so they need to have all information in one place. This is not a problem with a database application, but this is a real-time data acquisition app where the data is coming too fast for a database architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get this to work with the [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx), by using its [`VirtualMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx).

But there are some subtle things you have to check to get the most performance out of it. All these questions for the best performance are answered in the [DataGridView FAQ](http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc). So read it carefully to get the most out of it.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully, you have my answer in the [Telerik Forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/fast-and-responsive-gridview-for-data-acquisition.aspx), but in case you haven't, I'll post it here too.

> Whilst I can't specifically say yes to all of your questions without fully testing the scenario, I can give you a recommendation from my own experience of using the RadGridView.
>
> We use the RadGridView, and indeed all of the Telerik controls for WinForms in a variety of different types of forms, some of which collect data on a minute by minute basis. The feature set of the Telerik RadGridView is second to none and performance is generally excellent. (have a look at the demos on your PC under GridView >> Performance >> Load 50,000 rows and High Refresh.)
>
> The Telerik controls generally follow the same implementations as the standard Microsoft grid, but with obvious feature enhancements. In honesty, any GridView component that implements this many features is never going to be quite as fast as the standard control, but for us at least, the additional benefits that come from the themes, and range of features far outweigh any disadvantage.
>
> The RadGridView implements a neat UI Virtualization system that improves performance. This means that only the rows that are currently visible have a visual element. When the grid is scrolled up and down the visual elements are reused. This is obviously good for performance as the RadGridView does not create visual elements where it doesn't need to. You can read more about this structure in [this documntation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-fundamentals-logical-vs-visual-grid-structure.html).
>
> I hope this helps somewhat and that you choose to use Telerik's products. Personally, I firmly believe that they are the best on the market.
> All the best
> Richard